# "FALTA DESTINO DE DEPURACION" VS 2022

Tags: mysql, c#

Visual Studio no puede iniciar la depuración porque falta el destino de depuración 'D:\PROYECTO ALMACEN\PROYECTO ALMACEN\bin\Debug\PROYECTO_ALMACEN.exe'. Compile el proyecto e inténtelo de nuevo o establezca las propiedades OutputPath y AssemblyName correctamente para que indiquen la ubicación adecuada del ensamblado de  destino.

Estoy trabajando con VISUAL STUDIO 2022, no me genera PROYECTO_ALMACEN.exe en la carpeta destino. La ruta es correcta, names igual. Ya he compilado, recompilado, volver a generar proyecto; sigue apareciendo error cuando ejecuto. ¿Ayuda, por favor? Gracias!